# how to extend docker mysql image

Tags: mysql, docker

I pull the mysql/mysql-server image, then I execute the following commands below:

```
docker run --name myapp -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql/mysql-server
docker exec -it myapp bash
```

After this, I install jdk and tomcat in the newly created `myapp` container, then I exit the shell and run:

```
docker commit myapp myappwithjdk
```

Then I run the following, but the container exits immediately:

```
docker run -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d myappwithjdk
```

I don't know why it does this.

Comment: Do you mean that mysql-server exists right after being started?

Answer (score 3):

It could be leftovers from running mysql (like pid file). It is bad approach to use exec & commit for creating own container based on different one. Much better to create own image via [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/):

```
FROM mysql/mysql-server
RUN <your commands here>
```

and then

```
docker build -t myappwithjdk .
```

Comment: **ali gado** it's very useful

Comment: if i want to create database user and table ,should i write it in Dockerfile?

Comment: @leon whatever you want inside your container when it comes up, you can put that in Dockerfile.

Comment: I write " RUN mysql -uroot -pmy-secret-pw" in my Dockerfile but got this.  where is wrong? 
    
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'

Comment: Solution 2: use a script

Create an executable script init_db.sh:

#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/mysqld_safe &
sleep 5
mysql -u root -e "CREATE DATABASE mydb"
mysql -u root mydb < /tmp/dump.sql
Add these lines to your Dockerfile:

ADD init_db.sh /tmp/init_db.sh
RUN /tmp/init_db.sh   i do like this  but can not find mysqld file?

Comment: In most cases you want to keep database separate from container, in volume which either in data container or mapped to host filesystem. So it is a good idea to create start script or entrypoint which will create/populate db at first container run.

Answer (score 1):

The mysql image have the way to execute init scripts (both **bash** and **sql**) once on container creation. Simply put them to `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` folder:

```
FROM mysql:latest
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root

COPY 00-extra_env_setup.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/00-extra_env_setup.sh
COPY 01-user_setup.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/01-user_setup.sql
```

build:

```
docker build -t mymysql .
```

and run(note port exposing):

```
docker run -p 3306:3306 mymysql
```

now you able connect to it outside(change the ip to the ip of your docker server):

```
mysql --host 127.0.0.1 --port 3306 --user root --password
```

That's it!